# Is there any way to control my android phone remotely from another android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, remote-access

I have an Android Galaxy S4 Mini (SGH-I257) that is not rooted and running stock software Android 4.4.2 and an Samsung Galaxy Admire (SGH-R830C) rooted running stock Android 4.1.2. Both devices are fully updated.

I am trying to use my S4 Mini to control my Admire, is this possible? I have tried using TeamViewer and but that does not seem to be working. I tried droid VNC which worked but the interface was very clunky and it seemed to be made for computers.

I basically want to open an app on my Mini and have my Admire appear, like remote desktop connection. I don't need sound, but I would like to be able to click the home button remotely and be able to swipe the lock screen to unlock.

VNC works, but it will not work outside my home network which defeats the purpose. Could I host this via my modem I have? I have an At&T Uverse Motorola NVG589 modem running software version 9.1.0h12d34.

Comment: Port forwarding on your home router with a static IP could work.